# Position fix and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose two tables are in a row, when the user scrolls left the first table remains fixed. But when the user scrolls up both the tables scroll up.

Comment: please add html and css code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What HTML, Javascript, or CSS have you already tried that is currently not working as you intend it?

Comment: Can you state an example of yours or can u show a demo for my requirement dear.My code is in php many and very lengthy code.Please solve my issue if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple first you have to fix the height of the table then put this attribute in your style sheet class if you need y axis do the same in

```
.class{overflow-x:scroll;}
```